# How to apply original style on jQuery mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have applied a fadeout affect on a background image. How do I slowly apply back the original style on mouseout?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KevinOrin/H6Q3J/

```
jQuery('.square-section').mouseover(function(){
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow',0.3, function(){
        jQuery(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + $img + ')');
    }).fadeTo('slow',1);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the `$img variable` in the first place .. So the callback function is not required in the first..

The callback function might have been on help here if you are changing the image completely.

```
jQuery('.square-section').hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow',0.3);
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow',1);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/H6Q3J/2/)**

If you want to swap 2 different images you can try this approach

```
jQuery('.square-section').hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function() {
        jQuery('.square', this).removeClass('square-chess').addClass('square-chart');
        jQuery(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.3, function() {
       jQuery('.square', this).removeClass('square-chart').addClass('square-chess');
       jQuery(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle with 2 images](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/H6Q3J/4/)**

```
jQuery('.square-section').hover(function () {
    jQuery('.square', this).removeClass('square-chess').addClass('square-chart');
}, function () {
    jQuery('.square', this).removeClass('square-chart').addClass('square-chess');
});
```

Comment: That works well, but I guess my original fiddle never did what it was suppose to. I would like the background image opacity to fade in and out on mouseover while the text remains at the same opacity.

Comment: Right.. So you would not require the callback or change the image

Comment: So how can I use this effect to target/fade just the background image and not the div/text

Comment: For that you would need to use 2 different images. One before and after

Comment: Gotcha, in that case I wouldn't need the fadeTo then...just a faded image and a regular one.

Comment: Yup.. that's right.. You can completely remove the fadeTo and just specify a  delayed execution

Comment: could you possibly refactor the jsfiddle without the fade. cant seem to do it

Comment: Don't forget the `.stop()` so that you don't get a flashing tile! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.square-section').mouseout(function(){
    jQuery(this).fadeTo('slow',0.3, function(){
        jQuery(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + $img + ')');
    }).fadeIn('slow',1);
});
```

Comment: The only difference there is the .mouseout. If I add this in addition to my js it would have not effect, and if I replace my js with it the image would fade on mouseout and there would still be no way to get it back to original opacity.